# PHP: get folder user space and return as percentage related to total user space

Tags: php

I'm doing a function to calculate the current used space ( calculating directory size) and compare to available user space ( eg 10MB ), then it will return in a percentage number to fill a progress bar.

```
function getDirSpaceLeft($totalSpace) {
   $f = 'data/';
   $io = popen ( '/usr/bin/du -sk ' . $f, 'r' );
   $size = fgets ( $io, 4096);
   $size = substr ( $size, 0, strpos ( $size, "\t" ) );
   pclose ( $io );
   $current = $totalSpace - $size;
   $precent = $current * 100 / 2;
   return $precent;
}
```

But using this code it will return a strange number like 523557400 if I pass a value of 10Mb (10485760) to function.

I think I'm doing something wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function I found (not mine) which returns the size used by files in the folder (including subfolders) in bytes:

```
/*  Get size of files in folder including subfolders, in bytes.
    From: https://gist.github.com/eusonlito/5099936
*/
function getSizeUsed($dir) {
    $size = 0;
    foreach (glob(rtrim($dir, '/').'/*', GLOB_NOSORT) as $each)
        $size += is_file($each) ? filesize($each) : getSizeUsed($each);
    return $size;
}
```

You can then calculate the percentage of the total used, as follows:

```
$total = 10000000;
$dir = "data/";
echo (getSizeUsed($dir)/$total)*100;
```

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't a fix for your code, this is how I did mine...

```
<?php

// folder to check
$dir = '/';

// get disk space free (in bytes)
$disk_free = disk_free_space($dir);

// get disk space total (in bytes)
$disk_total = disk_total_space($dir);

// calculate the disk space used (in bytes)
$disk_used = $disk_total - $disk_free;

// percentage of disk used
$disk_used_p = sprintf('%.2f',($disk_used / $disk_total) * 100);

// this function will convert bytes value to KB, MB, GB and TB
function convertSize( $bytes )
{
        $sizes = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB' );
        for( $i = 0; $bytes >= 1024 && $i < ( count( $sizes ) -1 ); $bytes /= 1024, $i++ );
                return( round( $bytes, 2 ) . " " . $sizes[$i] );
}

// format the disk sizes using the function (B, KB, MB, GB and TB)
$disk_free = convertSize($disk_free);
$disk_used = convertSize($disk_used);
$disk_total = convertSize($disk_total);

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>Total: '.$disk_total.'</li>';
echo '<li>Used: '.$disk_used.' ('.$disk_used_p.'%)</li>';
echo '<li>Free: '.$disk_free.'</li>';
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

---

PHP Manual:

1. [disk_total_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-total-space.php)
2. [disk_free_space()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php)

Comment: This can't be used for my purpose, cause I need to check the space used in a folder not entire disk, like a "Google Drive" I got many folders related to many users, every user got some free space, so I need to calculate the used space related to given space.